# Python Ray shared memory access

Tags: python, redis, multiprocessing, shared-memory, ray

I have a question concerning the access of the shared memory within the Ray Framework.
Imagine the following setup on **1 machine**:

1. Start Ray cluster
2. Start a process/worker python script **w1.py**, which puts an object **O1** into the shared memory via *ray.put(O1)*
3. Start a process/worker python script **w2.p**y, which tries to get **O1** from the shared memory via *ray.get(...)*

Is there a way to access the object **O1** (put into shared memory from **w1.py** process) from another worker process **w2.py**?

When I execute *ray.objects()* from **w2.py**, I get the obejct reference string, but how could I retrieve the object from the shared memory then? I can not init a *ObjectRef object* in **w2.py**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not natively supported. The reason is ray’s objects have various metadata that is for various features (ex, perf optimization or automatic memory management using reference counting).

If you’d like to achieve this, I think there are 2 solutions.

1. Use a detached actor api. Detached actors are actors whose lifetime is not fare-sharing with drivers. Once you create a detached actor, you can obtain the actor handle using ray.get_actor API. This way, you can put an object inside a detached actor and access from multiple drivers.
2. There’s another way which uses cloudpickle, but I am not so familiar with this solution, so I won’t write about it. Please go to Ray’s discussion page in its Github repo to ask more details about it.